# Static cell changing height when switch is on

Tags: swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath, jtapplecalendar

HI I am programming an app which I want the height of a cell to change if the switch is on, I had it working before then I needed to copy my files over to a new project.[This works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auPTr.png) then I make a small change to return 0 instead [This does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JceRl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest code from the master. I think this looks likes a similar issue I found on their GitHub. Have a look:-

http://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/304

Comment: Hi I have no protocol function that I've used, I only checked if the switch was on and is the indexPath was right then changed the height, maybe there are better ways to do it, but this worked before so I stuck with it. I tried using your code but I got error at (cell: customCell) and isButtonOn lines. Any ideas? btw I'm new to swift and programming in general

Comment: of course you will get an error, as this code only explains the concept and is not a full implementation of the thing. I meant to ask you whether each cell has a button like this or the button is outside the tableview ( not belonging to the tableviewcell ) ?

Comment: the table looks like this http://imgur.com/a/67Ejq so the button is in another cell.

Comment: that calendar will shrink if the button is off ? Is the calendar made in tableviewcell itself?

Comment: Yes it will shrink to the size it was from the beginning. At the moment it will crash if the start size is less than 80 or something like that

Comment: oh okay, and that's why you return 0 it crashes because it needs minimum 80

Comment: is this any third party lib you are using ?

Comment: make sure you are using the latest code from the master. I think this looks likes a similar issue I found on their GitHub. Have a look:- https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/304

Comment: Thank you very much it works now! I had to update to the latest version. Should I accept your first answer as correct?